# No joint distribution for set of random variables

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

What is a system described by a set of random variables for which there are distributions over subsets of these variables which are not marginal of a distribution over all random variables at once.
That is, what is an example of contextual statistics in the real world.
I would like an example that is not quantum mechanics please

Comment: Hi: I don't know of a particular example but there are cases where one can have joint normality with some covariance matrix and the marginals are not normally distributed. Note that the joint and marginals exist but the marginals aren't normal so that may not be what you are looking for.